# Is undefined versus undefined behavior

Tags: c++

The cppreference wording on `front` and `back` is surprisingly (at least for me) asymmetric.

[front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front):

> Calling `front` on an empty container is undefined.

[back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)

> Calling `back` on an empty container causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

I know I am supposed to ask only one question, but still,

1. Why it is different?, and
2. What is the difference between *is undefined* and *causes undefined behavior*?

Comment: They mean the same in this context.

Comment: I would be surprised if there's any genuine semantic significance to the difference, as opposed to different pages not quite getting updated to the exact same style guide standard. Similarly, I'd be surprised if there's any great difference between "reference" with a lower-case 'r' and "Reference" with a capital 'r'

Comment: _"Why it is different?"_ because we don't write with the exact same words every single time?

Comment: Semantically in English they do imply a subtle difference, however in that sense that is an error in the cppreference text rather than a difference in the C++ semantics.

Comment: Noticing small details like that is a useful programmer's skill.

Comment: As for the 02/Nov/2023, the `front`page  is already fixed and it uses the same term as the `back` page: "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between is undefined and causes undefined behavior?

They have the same meaning here.

---

> Why it is different?,

Most likely because the page has been written by different authors or/and has not been updated for quite some time. Still, both are intended to mean the same thing.

---

##### Update

The page has now been updated to make the documentation language more consistent. In particular, now [front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) says:

> Calling front on an empty container **causes undefined behavior**.

Comment: And in a few minutes, it will say "Calling front on an empty container causes undefined behavior, and may email your browser history to your grandmother before formatting your hard drive."  (Just kidding, that change wouldn't make it past editorial review.)

Comment: @Eljay Haha :)..

Answer (score 2):

In C++, there is no difference between "undefined" and "undefined behavior." Both terms refer to the same concept: a situation in which the standard does not specify the expected outcome of a certain operation.

Comment: Minor point: "undefined behavior" applies to **the program**, not just the operation that causes it. The usual way of writing that is "The behavior of a program is undefined if ...". The behavior isn't necessarily unpredictable; it just means that the C++ standard doesn't tell you what the program does. Compilers are free to provide their own rules where the standard says the behavior is undefined. +1.